# In Node-Red how can I change a string of letters to have a full stop between each letter

Tags: string, node-red

I am collecting some flight server data in Node Red and sending the data as a text string to Home Assistant to use with  Google TTS speech.  The issue I have is that the Callsign is a string of letters such as RYR1234GT, which I want to be spoken as characters not a word.  I know that a space or a full-stop between each character will do the trick (R.Y.R.1.2.3.4.G.T), but how can I change this in a Node-Red function?

I have tried but my javascript knowledge is not good.
I used substring in a function and got all the characters separated and used that forwarded to a JSON script to combine as a string. It all works with the addition of . and a(space), but its a bit ugly and of course the random length of the callsign is not calculated, but that didn't seem to matter if there was a blank string. Can you show me a better way.

This is my Node-Red nodes and flow, using function and change  nodes

```
[{"id":"da8a6ef0b3c9a5c8","type":"tab","label":"Flow 1","disabled":false,"info":"","env":[]},{"id":"ef9f06be11be1595","type":"inject","z":"da8a6ef0b3c9a5c8","name":"","props":[{"p":"payload"},{"p":"topic","vt":"str"}],"repeat":"","crontab":"","once":true,"onceDelay":0.1,"topic":"","payload":"BA2156R","payloadType":"str","x":340,"y":140,"wires":[["c25bd685916af4ca"]]},{"id":"777ae9cd4da78bd3","type":"debug","z":"da8a6ef0b3c9a5c8","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"false","statusVal":"","statusType":"auto","x":1150,"y":140,"wires":[]},{"id":"c25bd685916af4ca","type":"function","z":"da8a6ef0b3c9a5c8","name":"","func":"var call = msg.payload;\nlet one = call.substr(0,1);\nlet two = call.substr(1,1);\nlet three = call.substr(2,1);\nlet four = call.substr(3,1);\nlet five = call.substr(4,1);\nlet six = call.substr(5,1);\nlet seven = call.substr(6,1);\nlet eight = call.substr(7,1);\n\n\n//return {payload:{one}};\nreturn {payload:{one:one,two:two,three:three,four:four,five:five,six:six,seven:seven,eight:eight}}\n","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"initialize":"","finalize":"","libs":[],"x":560,"y":140,"wires":[["0fb13606396dd088"]]},{"id":"0fb13606396dd088","type":"change","z":"da8a6ef0b3c9a5c8","name":"","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"payload.all","pt":"msg","to":"$string(payload.one) & \".\" & $string(payload.two) & \".\" & $string(payload.three) & \".\" & $string(payload.four) & \".\" & $string(payload.five) & \".\" & $string(payload.six) & \".\" & $string(payload.seven) & \".\" & $string(payload.eight) & \".\" ","tot":"jsonata"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":750,"y":140,"wires":[["9442164bb3990b3f"]]},{"id":"9442164bb3990b3f","type":"change","z":"da8a6ef0b3c9a5c8","name":"","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"payload","pt":"msg","to":"payload.all","tot":"msg"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":970,"y":140,"wires":[["777ae9cd4da78bd3"]]},{"id":"3da6785dbcb2f779","type":"comment","z":"da8a6ef0b3c9a5c8","name":"Splitup a code with .'s","info":"Splitup a code with .'s","x":360,"y":80,"wires":[]}]
```

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74783990/edit) the question to show us what you tried and how it didn't work. We will not just supply code based on a requirement, but we will help you fix what you've already tried.

Comment: Don't describe the code, show it. Include sample input data so we know if the call sign is on its own or included in a larger string

Answer (score 0):

The following will work for any length of call sign.

It uses the split node to break the String into individual chars and then the join node to put them back together

[image: Split node breaking a string into chars]

[image: Join node inserting '.' between each char]

```
[
    {
        "id": "ef9f06be11be1595",
        "type": "inject",
        "z": "da8a6ef0b3c9a5c8",
        "name": "",
        "props": [
            {
                "p": "payload"
            },
            {
                "p": "topic",
                "vt": "str"
            }
        ],
        "repeat": "",
        "crontab": "",
        "once": true,
        "onceDelay": 0.1,
        "topic": "",
        "payload": "BA2156R",
        "payloadType": "str",
        "x": 160,
        "y": 220,
        "wires": [
            [
                "4c86e9ed4d1a16b8"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "4c86e9ed4d1a16b8",
        "type": "split",
        "z": "da8a6ef0b3c9a5c8",
        "name": "",
        "splt": "1",
        "spltType": "len",
        "arraySplt": 1,
        "arraySpltType": "len",
        "stream": false,
        "addname": "",
        "x": 290,
        "y": 220,
        "wires": [
            [
                "902d89b62bc29fbb"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "72ada8de8633d357",
        "type": "debug",
        "z": "da8a6ef0b3c9a5c8",
        "name": "debug 1",
        "active": true,
        "tosidebar": true,
        "console": false,
        "tostatus": false,
        "complete": "false",
        "statusVal": "",
        "statusType": "auto",
        "x": 540,
        "y": 220,
        "wires": []
    },
    {
        "id": "902d89b62bc29fbb",
        "type": "join",
        "z": "da8a6ef0b3c9a5c8",
        "name": "",
        "mode": "custom",
        "build": "string",
        "property": "payload",
        "propertyType": "msg",
        "key": "topic",
        "joiner": ".",
        "joinerType": "str",
        "accumulate": false,
        "timeout": "",
        "count": "",
        "reduceRight": false,
        "reduceExp": "",
        "reduceInit": "",
        "reduceInitType": "",
        "reduceFixup": "",
        "x": 410,
        "y": 220,
        "wires": [
            [
                "72ada8de8633d357"
            ]
        ]
    }
]
```